# Edit and delete an event in Facebook using Javascript SDK

Tags: facebook

How can I edit and delete an event in Facebook using the Javascript SDK? I've been Googling for a day with no sucess!

Thanks for any help!

UPDATE:

After banging my head on the wall several times, I've finally discovered how to accomplish these tasks:

- To edit an event:

  FB.api("/"+event_id,
      'post',
          {
          name: evname,
          start_time:"2011-08-25T12:00:00",
          end_time:"2011-08-25T23:00:00",
          location: address,
          description: desc
          } ,
      function(resp) {
          alert('ok');
      });
- To delete an event:

  FB.api("/"+event_id,
      'delete',
      function(resp) {
          alert('ok');
      });

Comment: Please post this as as answer.

Answer (score 2):

you have to post DELETE request to delete event

```
FB.api("/"+eventID, 'DELETE', function() { 
    //do stuff
});
```

if you use FBJS